# "relevel" a set of columns using the for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to "relevel" a set of columns using the for loop.

```
    for(j in 8:ncol(trainVote)){
    trainVote$colnames(trainVote[j]) <- relevel(as.factor(trainVote$colnames(trainVote[j])), 
                                          which.max(table(trainVote$colnames(trainVote[j]))))
    }
```

Error: Error in is.factor(x) : attempt to apply non-function

Any help in what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `trainVote` look like? Is `trainVote$colnames` a function? If it is not, then that is likely to cause the error. You are using round brackets to index `trainVote$colnames`. R interprets this as a function evaluation and looks for a function at that point. Have you tried using square brackets?

Comment: colnames is an inbuilt function in R. colnames(trainVote[j]) returns the name of the column, where j is the integer value from the "for" loop.

Comment: `colnames` is a function but R is trying to evaluate the function `trainVote$colnames` not `colnames`. `trainVote$colnames` is just the element with the name `colnames` in a list (or data frame) called `trainVote`. Could you show us what your data looks like, e.g. by showing the output of `str(trainVote)`?

Comment: trainVote has 108 columns. `str` might not be the best thing. the columns are `character` type.

Comment: what could be a better approach if I am to `relevel` multiple columns in one go?

Comment: Does this work? `for (j in 8:ncol(trainVote)){
 trainVote[,j] <- relevel(as.factor(trainVote[,j]),
   names(which.max(table(trainVote[,j])))) 
}`

Comment: wow!! it works!! ty ty ty!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140062/discussion-between-tanmoy-and-ikop).